# Django: Object's ManyToMany Add/Remove Functions Update Database but Not Object

Tags: python, django

I have various ManyToMany relationships in the code I'm working with. Setups are basically like:

```
class Account(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=32, unique=True)
    roles = models.ManyToManyField('Role', related_name='accounts')

class Role(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=32, unique=True)
```

So, playing with this setup in the shell I get:

```
>>> Account.objects.all()
[<Account: Account name:"Account 1">]
>>> Role.objects.all()
[<Role: Role name:"Role 1">, <Role: Role name:"Role 2">]
>>> a = Account.objects.get(name='Account 1')
>>> a.roles.all()
[<Role: Role name:"Role 1">]
>>> r = Role.object.get(name='Role 2')
>>> r.accounts.all()
[]
>>> a.roles.add(r)
>>> a.roles.all()
[<Role: Role name:"Role 1">]
>>> r.accounts.all()
[]
```

The appropriate Account/Role objects aren't updating with the add function. But if I regrab the objects from the database:

```
>>> a = Account.objects.get(name='Account 1')
>>> a.roles.all()
[<Role: Role name:"Role 1">, <Role: Role name:"Role 2">]
>>> r = Role.object.get(name='Role 2')
>>> r.accounts.all()
[<Account: Account name:"Account 1">]
```

Now, things are properly updated.

I'm getting this same problem when running code in proper files.

The project is using Django 1.8, and from [its many-to-many documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/), it looks like this behavior shouldn't be happening....

When I tried to replicate this behavior on a different project, I couldn't do it, so I'm guessing the project is setup somehow to cause this behavior. Is there a variable or library or something that causes this?

Comment: Django tries to minimize the amount of database queries it does, because that can be a significant performance bottleneck. In this case maybe `r.accounts.all()` is cached? It's not supposed to be cached, according to the django docs, though.